# apply sum along subsets of array 3rd dimension

Tags: arrays, r, apply, seq

I have the following objects:

**A**: 1 array with x,y,z, dimensions -> containing a variable (Temperature)

**B** & **C**: 2 arrays with x,y dimensions -> containing the indices of vectors along A's z dimension

```
A <- array(rnorm(n = 12*4*3*5), dim = c(4,3,5))
dimnames(A) <- list("x" = c(1:4), "y" = c(1:3), "z" = c(1:5))

B <- matrix(rep(c(2:1), 6), nrow = 4)
dimnames(B) <- list("x" = c(1:4), "y" = c(1:3))
C <- matrix(rep(c(4:5), 6), nrow = 4)
dimnames(C) <- list("x" = c(1:4), "y" = c(1:3))
```

I'm looking for a way to apply sum of A across the z dimension only between the indices indicated by B and C.

If instead of the 3D-array I had a vector I would solve it like this:

```
> A <- round(c(rnorm(5)), 1)
> B <- 2 #index of first value to sum
> C <- 4 #index of last value to sum
> vindex <- seq(B,C,1)
> A
[1]  0.0 -0.9 -1.1 -1.7 -0.4
> vindex
[1] 2 3 4
> sum(A[vindex])
[1] -3.7
>

# or better with a function

> foo <- function(x, start_idx, end_idx) {
+   vidx <- seq(start_idx, end_idx, 1)
+   return(sum(x[vidx]))
+ }
> 
> foo(A,B,C)
[1] -3.7
```

Unfortunately seq() does not accept vectors as arguments and therefore it's not straightforward to use the apply function. If again were A[x,y,z] and B and C[x,y]:

```
> apply(A,c(1,2),foo,B,C)
Error in seq.default(start_idx, end_idx, 1) : 'from' must be of length 1
Called from: seq.default(start_idx, end_idx, 1)
```

It would be great if anybody knew how to make this function workable with apply or with other clean solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very nice task for base R, and I would prefer to implement it in C++ in the absence of a package that already does so (?).

Logically speaking, a plain but vectorized solution to your problem could be structured as:

```
# initialize index array
D <- array(
  1, 
  dim = c(4,3,5), 
  dimnames = list(x = letters[1:4], y = letters[1:3], z = letters[1:5])
)

# set indices out of bounds to zero
E <- rep(1:5, each = 4*3)
BB <- rep(B, times = 5)
D[E < BB] <- 0
CC <- rep(C, times = 5)
D[E > CC] <- 0

# multiply with index array and sum
apply(A * D, c(1,2), sum)
```